# How to loop over a file having multiple columns to execute an AWK script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with multiple columns (greater than 1000). Each column has numbers 0, 1 or some other. The tab delimited file looks like :

```
0   0   0    
0   0   0    
1   2   0    
1   0   0    
1   1   0
```

I want to calculate the occurrence of each unique digit for each column in the file. How do I do that using AWK or shell ?

P.S To calculate the occurrence of each unique digit in first column, i used AWK code :

```
awk '{h[$1]++}; END {for (k in h) print k, h[k]}' file > output-file
```

It gives the results as :

```
0  2
1  3
```

which means `0` occurs twice in column 1 and `1` occurs thrice in column 1.

I want to do the same for a file having over 1000 columns.

Comment: You can loop over the columns with `for (col = 1; col <= NF; col++)` and then use `$col` to access the value in the column.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input so we're not guessing.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make the keys for associative array `h` contain both column number, `i`, and column value, `$i`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) h[i" "$i]++}; END {for (k in h) print k, h[k]}' file | sort -n
1 0 2
1 1 3
2 0 3
2 1 1
2 2 1
3 0 5
```

The last line above indicates that column 3 has the value 0 occurring 5 times.

In more detail:

- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) h[i" "$i]++`

  This loops over all columns from the first, `i-=1`, to the last, `i=NF`.  For each column, it updates the counter `h` for that column and its value.
- `END {for (k in h) print k, h[k]}`

  This prints a table of the output.
- `sort -n`

  Because `for (k in h)` does not produce keys in any particular order, we put the output through sort.

Answer (score 0):

With awk 4.0 2D arrays

sample input matrix of n=3 columns containing integer values

```
0  0  0
0  0  0
1  2  0
1  0  0
1  1  0
4  0  0
7 -1 -2
```

output is vector of data values in column 0 that occur in input followed by matrix of n=3 columns with count of each data value in corresponding column of input matrix

```
-1 0 1 0 
-2 0 0 1 
 0 2 4 6 
 1 3 1 0 
 2 0 1 0 
 4 1 0 0 
 7 1 0 0
```

code

```
awk '
NR==1 {ncols=NF}
{for(i=1; i <=NF; ++i) ++c[$i][i-1]}
END{
  for(i in c) {
    printf("%d ", i)
    for(j=0; j < ncols; ++j) {
      printf("%d ", j in c[i]?c[i][j]: 0)
    }
    printf("\n")
  }
}
'
```

Comment: There's no need for the ncols variable since NF is preserved in the END section, printf is a builtin,not a function, so `printf(...)` doesn't do what you think it does, always favor `print ""` over `printf "\n"` so you're not hard-coding what you assume the ORS value to be, and that will leave a spurios blank character at the end of each line.